# Simulate rows with nth-child() and <li> without Classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have to style a list of items received from the BackEnd. Currently I'm just getting `<li>` elements, lots of them.

I've been asked to draw them table-like (i.e rows). In order to be legible, I wanted to set odd "rows" with a background color, and "even" rows with another.

I tried to achieve this effect with the `nth-child()` selector , but couldn't accomplish this task in any way I can figure out.

WHAT I KNOW for sure: the number of columns I'll have to draw the `<li>` elements (3). All `<li>` tags are equal (no specific classes or ids)

WHAT I DON'T KNOW: the amount of `<li>` elements I'm getting from Backend.

What I did was to set them with a width in % and float them.
What I couldn't achieve was to alternate background in rows.

The final list should look that the one from the example attached, but using `nth-child()` or similar instead of manually:

http://codepen.io/barleby/pen/dpkjmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nth-child selector can use a formula to select items:

```
li {
     width:30%;
     background-color:grey;
     float:left;
     padding:10px;
     margin:10px;
     list-style-type:none;
}

li:nth-child(6n+4), li:nth-child(6n+5), li:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background-color: #298EB2;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP has already stated they've tried `nth-child` but couldn't get it working, and the formulas copied here don't create an alternating row effect.

Comment: Author stated he couldn't get nth-child to work correctly, not that nth-child was unacceptable. My code makes items 4,5,6 out of every six use the alternate background color and he is using rows of 3 columns, so this does create the alternating row effect in his specific case.

Comment: K Richardson is right. His answer is what I was looking for. And,as I explained before, only limitation for this is that you have to know the number of cols you are displaying beforehand (otherwise Maths won't work). So if the site is responsive and eventually will narrow to 2 cols, according to Richardson solution, it'd be like:
`li:nth-child(4n+3), li:nth-child(4n+4){
    background-color: #298EB2;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child` and `even` or `odd` to select the `li`s you're interested in targeting.

For example:.

```
li:nth-child(even){
    background-color: red;
}
```

See [this article](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) for a bit more info.

Comment: That wouldn't work, Problem is that `<li>` elements are floated left. So using `even`would highlight one yes, one no, one yes, alternatively.